# Using data visualization in AR with ARKit

Tags: data-visualization, augmented-reality, arkit

I am new to iOS swift programming and to building AR apps with ARKIT. I find that ARKIT is more powerful than I imagined and I can able to achieve all my business case but except placing data dashboards or charts in AR 3d space. I found ARCharts on Google but it seems to be useless.

My business case is actually scan the object or product and recognize it and display data related to it on AR world which should also show some data analytics dashboard for sales trends of the product.

How to achieve this.. pls provide some inputs

Answer (score 0):

Using ARKit you will be able to detect image detection, object detection and plane detection. For your business case, you can use image detection and object detection.

I will recommend you to go through the below tutorial to get some basic knowledge on object detection and image detection.
[Building a Museum App with ARKit 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6957-building-a-museum-app-with-arkit-2). Happy coding ;)